# 2D map with current user position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm just started to learn unity and game dev. I have question

I want to create Map. This map will get array from server with "starts" and probably img for current map
User will travel from star to star.

Questions are:

1) Let say I return 11 stars and img for curernt map:

[image]

1)- How I can show where are user now. On server I can know that he travel from 2 to 3 star and I know that user will there(star #3) in 4min - how I can put "user point" between 2-3 start and each second move user point closer to 3star?

what is best practies for create dynamic map -- I mean - when user will finish his play on 11 start - i want to return to user new map with new dynamic start and he will start new map travelling

thnak you and sorry for English grammar.

Answer (score 2):

> how I can put "user point" between 2-3 start and each second move user
>   point closer to 3star?

Use `Vector2.Lerp` to do that. Pass in the first location and the second location, then pass in 0.5(**half**) to the time parameter It should return the **mid point** between the first and the second location.

A helper function to do this:

```
Vector2 getMidPoint(Vector2 userPointA, Vector2 userPointB)
{
    return Vector2.Lerp(userPointA, userPointB, 0.5f);
}
```

> I can know that he travel from 2 to 3 star and I know that user will
>   there(star #3) in 4min

```
IEnumerator moveWithinTime(GameObject playerToMove, Vector2 fromPointA, Vector2 toPointB, float byTime)
{
    float counter = 0;

    while (counter < byTime)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        playerToMove.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(fromPointA, toPointB, counter / byTime);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

And to call it,  `StartCoroutine(moveWithinTime(gameObject, gameObject.transform.position, new Vector2(10f, 10f), 4));`

Comment: thanks. Now question is....When I return from server starrs - I need give them just params for pistions and show on the map scene
I mean i will return now somethin like:
{ starName = "Name", vector = here is params for postion on map, and img url - for customize view of star} ??

Comment: @David I updated my answer. Your question and your comment are very hard to understand but I think I know a **little bit** of what you are trying to do. The new function I added can be used to move player from one position to another within time(4 minutes).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah - I'm sry for my grammar :(
In my last comment I try to ask -- how I can to know A and B vector -- and if I understand right - I can return it from server. And in this way i can dynamic put start on the map

Comment: **how I can to know A and B vector?** A is the current position of the object you want to move. You can get  it by doing `gameObject.transform.position` .B is the position you want to go to. So let's say that the object is in position 1 and you want to go to position 2, the A position is `gameObject.transform.position` and the B position is your position 2. It is your responsibility to determine what position 2,3,4,5,6... are. You can define them and put them into Vector2[] array. Or you can receive them from the network like you mentioned.

Comment: Are those times actually fixed or was that an example? If the times are not fixed you probably need something to map the distance in the game to the distance on the map. So, in the game have a start and an end marker and calculate the position of the player on the vector between these two and then set the player marker on the map to fit that relative position between the corresponding stars.

Comment: @GunnarB. **Are those times actually fixed or was that an example?** Is this question directed to me?

Comment: @Programmer No, to David. If I understand his question right he basically wants a real time player to map mapping.

Comment: If the times for each level are fixed (e.g. because the player is autorunning) then yours will do it, otherwise he will have to do some calculation.

Comment: @GunnarB. Ok. I don't understand the rest of his question like you do. I read that over and over again but yeah. He said something about **user will there(star #3) in 4min** so I guess he want to move user within time....Not really sure....

Comment: I don't quite understand what of both he wants, thats why im asking :D